# create a lzma file in python

Tags: python, zip, tar, lzma

i need to create a lzma file with the existing .tar file and another metadata file to further create a zip file.

Answer (score 1):

first [download/install PyLZMA](http://www.joachim-bauch.de/projects/pylzma/). In your program, use it as described [here](http://github.com/fancycode/pylzma/blob/master/doc/usage.txt). And to create a zip, you can use the [zipFile](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html)-module of the standard-library, which works [as follows](http://effbot.org/librarybook/zipfile.htm):

```
# open the zip file for writing, and write stuff to it

file = zipfile.ZipFile("test.zip", "w")

for name in a_demo_list_of_files:
    file.write(name, os.path.basename(name), zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

file.close()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: `zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED` uses `zlib`. Use `zipfile.ZIP_LZMA` to use `lzma`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

Answer (score 0):

if you can use python 3.3 and later, you could use the built-in lzma module